# Set value based on all conditions inside FOR loop

Tags: java

I need to set boolean value only when all the conditions are set. I am struggling to set the boolean value inside the for loop. As per my code the value is set TRUE/FALSE based on last item in the list. But the value should set only when all conditions are set. Could someone help me on this?

```
boolean validateName(List<String> NameList, Name name) {
        boolean value = false;
        for (String name : NameList) {
            name.hasName(name);
            value = true;
        }
        return value;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using a conditional block?

Comment: wouldn't be a clash between two variables of same names `name`?  does your program compile? Also, your question is not clear about **when all conditions are set**. What are those conditions?

Comment: use  if (nameList.contains(name))  i dont see point of using loop.

Answer (score 2):

Return `false` as soon as one condition is not met.

```
boolean validateName(List<String> NameList, Name aName) {
        boolean value = false;
        for (String name : NameList) {
            if(!aName.hasName(name))
              return false;

        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes indeed, I will update to a compilable example.

Comment: thanks, it will work. can we avoid ! operator here? is there any other options?

Comment: @ezhil why you prefer using for loop instead of  conditional block ?

Comment: i wanted to avoid conditional block since the if conditional block increase in future. I assume that it will more than 15 if condition. thats the reason i chosen this approach.

Comment: @ezhil : maybe the comment by RishiKesh Pathak  could help. Provided that `Name` has a unique name String, and a method like `String getName()`, you could do `NameList.contains(name.getName())` and just return this result from your method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
boolean validateName(List<String> nameList, Name name) {
   for (String nameTmp : nameList) {
      if(!nameTmp.equals(name))
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using Java 8:

```
return NameList.stream().allMatch(element -> element.equals(name))
```